# Trying to run Discord bot | CLUSTER_LINK, CLUSTER_ELEMENT, DB_ELEMENT.... What are those?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, github, discord, discord.py

Hi I am new to discord bot and python, and I have been trying to run this bot on railway.app.
https://github.com/Adgonzalez2018/Predictions-Bot

I have learned that to run this bot, I need to put some environment variables such as bot tokens.
I put Token, Guild, Channel1 - 3, but I have no idea what CLUSTER_LINK, CLUSTER_ELEMENT, DB_ELEMENT are.
I got a feeling that these are related to mongoDB and after googling for hours I still have no clue.
Could you help me with this? Any answers are appreciated.

```
import time
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
import Functions
from threading import Timer
import random
from pymongo import MongoClient
import math
import datetime
# global vars
intents = discord.Intents.all()
believePool, doubtPool, globalDict, guildMember, payOutPool = {}, {}, {}, {}, {}
global posts, cluster
startComDescription = "If the title/blv/dbt is more than one word use \"\". t is the time and is in seconds i.e. t = 120 = 2 minutes (Only admins can use)"
giveComDescription = "Gives points to specific member, you have to type their discord NAME (Only admins can use)."
refundComDescription = "Refunds points and stops prediction (Only admins can use)."
wonComDescription = "Sets win after a prediction has started, side = \"blv\" or \"dbt\" (Only admins can use)."
TOKEN, GUILD, CHANNEL1, CHANNEL2, CHANNEL3 = os.getenv("Token"), os.getenv("Guild"), os.getenv("Channel1"), os.getenv("Channel2"), os.getenv("Channel3")
CLUSTER_LINK, CLUSTER_ELEMENT, DB_ELEMENT = os.getenv("ClusterLink"), os.getenv("PointsData"), os.getenv("UserPoints")
cluster = MongoClient(CLUSTER_LINK)
```

-learned basics about environment variables of python
-learned basics about mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Going through the link you provided, it looks (to me at least) that the CLUSTER_ELEMENT and DB_ELEMENT are not required fields (in fact I cannot find references to them besides them being asked for). As such, I would either leave them empty (or put just random things, so the code runs depending on how it is setup).

As for CLUSTER_LINK, it is a MongoDB URI format. It depends on your MongoDB setup, but you can read more about it on the MongoDB docs [here](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-connection-string).